# Angular Compiler Error after update to Version 9

Tags: compiler-errors, ivy, angular9

After upgrading to Angular 9 i get a strange compiler error. I have updated 4 projects, 3 without any problems but the last one throws this error:

```
ERROR in Error: [class] and [className] bindings cannot be used on the same element simultaneously
    at StylingBuilder.registerClassInput (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13564:27)
    at StylingBuilder.registerInputBasedOnName (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13527:36)
    at StylingBuilder.registerBoundInput (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13503:36)
    at C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17296:57
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.visitElement (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17295:28)
    at Element.visit (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4268:71)
    at visitAll (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:4435:40)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16982:13)
    at C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17558:60
    at C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16992:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16992:37)
    at C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17558:60
    at C:\Users\kschramm\Documents\arzneimittel-wechsler\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:16992:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I have no idea what is causing this error, has anybody any idea?

Comment: can you post the code which generating the error incase you have it

Comment: It is a whole project, i don't know which part of the code generates the error. The error comes in ng serve and ng build

Comment: Please follow the link? https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 5):

I checked my code and found the reason for the error. It was a html element with two regular class decorators. Just a simple copy issue, but ivy 
doesn't seem to like it :D

Comment: work for me, my element look like:
`<div [class]='blabla1' [class]= 'blabla2'></div>`

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue where I had to track down an occurrence of a double class on a massive application (yikes).
this regex in vs-code helped a ton.

search with regex enabled:

```
class=".*".*class  // single line
class=".*"[^>\r\n]*(\r\n|\r|\n)[^>\r\n]*class // class on a new line
class=".*"[^>\r\n]*(\r\n|\r|\n)[^>\r\n]*(\r\n|\r|\n)[^>\r\n]*class // class on the second line away
```

I wasn't sure of a great way to deal with the classes occuring on variable lines, so I just added another iteration of `[^>\r\n]*(\r\n|\r|\n)` before the second `class` keyword.

Hope it helps someone else!

Comment: Thanks for this!  Massively helped. I had a few repeated class="" class="" and [class]="" [class]=""

Answer (score 2):

Search your project for every html element with [class] AND [className] in it. In my case it was an older plugin (in node_modules) that was not yet adapted to Angular 9. After I removed [className] (I don't need it), it worked fine. Hint was that the compiling stoppped at the plugin which had the error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is quite clear but it's difficult to find where exactly it has been generated.

In my case the offending template that was something like:

```
<div class="classA {{ some_object.propertyB }}"
     [class.classC]="some_object.propertyC">
```

and I have fixed it converting it to:

```
<div class="classA" [ngClass]="{
     'classX': some_condition,
     'classC': some_object.propertyC}">
```

Basically, I have had to move all the bindings to a single `ngClass`.

A link that might be usefull:

- [fix(ivy): handling className as an input properly](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/33188)

Answer (score 0):

I had issue when a class attribute was defined next to [class]. It was really hard to find the source in a large codebase as the error log is not explicit !

The issue was :

```
<i class="menu-icons-style" [class]="topBarElement.class"></i>
```

The fix was to simply use ngClass instead :

```
<i class="menu-icons-style" [ngClass]="topBarElement.class"></i>
```